# mySQL command line alternative - remote tools

Tags: triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a host with cPanel and need to create some Triggers but PhpMyAdmin does not support normal triggers so my second choice is to create them in the command line...my question is...does anyone know of any alternatives or tools I can use to make my life simpler?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use client tools on your computer? (You usually can't because port 3306 will be closed to external access.)

Comment: I can enable remove access if needed yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't promise anything as I haven't worked with the feature yet, but [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) is a pretty cool Windows client for mySQL and [seems to have implemented triggers.](http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=4689)